# Interior point of a subspace

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a vector space with norm $||·||$, and let $V \subseteq X$ be a linear subspace (i.e., $V$ is also a vector space with norm $||·||$), such that $\operatorname{int}(V) \neq \emptyset$. Show
that $V = X$. ($\operatorname{int}(V)$ is the set of interior points in $V$)

What I know:
So $V$ is a subset of $X$. Also $V$ is not empty. But the thing is that, if $V$ is a subspace of $X$, how do we know that there's no other points in $X$, that actually isn't in $V$? What kind of relations do these have?

I appreciate help. This is just a prep-exercise for exam.

Comment: every point in $\text{int}(V)$ has an open ball in $X$ contained in $\text{int}(V)$

Comment: Can you use any illustration?

Comment: Since $V$ is a vector space any linear combination in the open ball in $\text{int}(V)$ is in $V$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x \in X$ and consider the line segment $\{ t \cdot x : 0 \le t \le 1 \}$ from $x$ to the origin. There is a neighborhood of the origin contained in $V$. That neighborhood cuts at least some part $\{ t \cdot x : 0 \le t \le \epsilon \}$ of the line segment.
$V$ being a vector space, it must contain all multiples $t \cdot (\epsilon \cdot x)$ of $\epsilon \cdot x$, among which is $x$. So $V$ contains all of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be the set of scalars for $X.$ ($S=\mathbb R$ or $S=\mathbb C.$). For  any $r>0$ the set $A(r)= \{sy: \in S \land \|y\|\leq r\}$ is equal to $X.$

Because for $0\ne x\in X$  let  $y=rx/\|x\|$ and $s=\|x\|/r.$ And for $x=0$ let $y=0$ and let $s$ be any scalar.

If $v\in Int (V)$ take $k>0$ such that $\{x\in X: \|y-x\|<k\}\subset V.$  Let $r=k/2.$

Then for any  $y\in X,$ if $\|y\|\leq r$ then $v$ and $v+y$ both belong to $V$ so their difference $y$ also belongs to $V.$....So $V\supset A(r)=X.$